# Text Font Code Error

Tags: android

I am trying to change my font in one of my text views, but I think I am missing something here. I have my font in the assets folder so I know that's OK its just this error that's got me. 
I have tried

Hope you can help.

```
     Typeface tf =    
     Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AlexBrush-
         Regular-OTF.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTypeface(tf)
```

Comment: try replace the dash character on font name to underline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing my friend is ; at the end of your code. I have just tried your code in eclipse and its this error.

Hope this help you.

```
 Typeface tf =    
 Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AlexBrush-
     Regular-OTF.otf");
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Sometimes it the small things that get me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");
            sometextview.setTypeface(font);
```

I'd start with the name of your font - suffix ? dash ?

Oh ... and have you placed your font in the "fonts" subdirectory ?